# Optimize Table or MySQL Settings for Update/Inner-Join a large table

Tags: mysql, settings

This is related to a question I recently posted:

[Efficient way to flag a record with min field value and common fieldX value in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039902/efficient-way-to-flag-a-record-with-min-field-value-and-common-fieldx-value-in-m)

but similar errors are occurring on other queries that previously worked such as:

```
Update TableA as T1
Inner Join TableA as T2  
on T1.Field1=T2.FIeld1and T1.Field2 is not NULL
set T2.GroupFlag=T1.GroupFlag
```

All of a sudden, I am getting:

> ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

I have run this before several times on this same table and it worked, so clearly the query is OK.

I know this question is sort of vague, but I'm not sure how else to ask it. Is there something in MySQL settings that I should check? We did recently restore a backup of the database to a new (this) server, but the only difference, as far as I know, is that we doubled the size of the server to give us room to work with.

**UPDATE:**

I did find this:

https://major.io/2010/02/16/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-2/

which basically states that my innodb_buffer_pool is too small. I checked and our new server, though larger, never had the old settings of 2GB migrated and we only have 128MB.

so I will ask SysAdmin/DevOps to try this and report back to this question if it solves the issue (vs just removing the question since perhaps it will help someone else eventually).

Comment: This question and the other question both need additional data like your table structures and your indices etc.

Comment: @e4c5 Both questions it turns out relate to the innodb_buffer so I am experimenting with that and will update with results. As per the question nothing in the table structure, date or indices changed so the (new) server settings turns out to be the culprit. Meanwhile updated this and the other Q to reflect that.

Comment: Great to know that you figured it out on your own. No doubt you are aware that it's possible to answer your own question and accept it :-)

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks and yes I do. I am awaiting confirmation from SysAdmin when he gets in and changes settings and then will update with the specifics (size it was, size changed to, etc) and any other relevant info on the table/index sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so answer to the question was Mysql settings. Apparently when we migrated servers DevOps/SysAdmin did migrate settings but didn't restart server as I jumped right into query-mode. We restarted last night and things worked swimmingly.

The issue was that innodb_buffer_pool was set to 128MB by default and our custom settings had it at 2GB.